# Single variable to represent either one item, all items, or none

Tags: java

I'm writing a method that accepts a UUID to represent items in an XML.  What's the best way to special-purpose a value that represents "all" or "none"?  I think it may be best not to make up UUIDs to represent all or none. Would I be better off creating a wrapper class that contains private variable flags for all or none?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [`enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) like,

```
enum SelectionType {
    ONE, ALL, NONE;
}
```

Comment: I believe that "one" must also be, or contain, an actual uuid, but OP can clarify.

Comment: Correct, that would need to be something like a UUID.  I'd like to be able to hold multiple UUIDs too.  So I'm thinking I need an object that contains a Set of UUIDs, and then maybe an enum inside the class that holds NONE or ALL.  If the enum is not null, then use that value to see if this object means NONE or ALL, otherwise return the UUID(s).  I was trying to avoid having to write logic for this but I don't see another way.

Comment: See my answer below.  For a Set, none is easy, and you could use null, or a special Set, to indicate all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest implementation would be an array (or List) of UUIDs.  However this assumes you actually know "all" of the UUIDs.  "None"is covered.  For "all", if you don't know all the UUIDs, have null be a special case, or else use a special constant.  e.g.

`public static final UUID[] ALL = new UUID[0];`

And in your code

```
if (inArray == ALL)
   handleAllCase();
else
   onlyHandleUUIDsInArray(inArray);
```

Another possibility would be a range of UUIDs, with min and max.  If max equals min it means "one", if max less than min it means "none", and for all you set min to the smallest possible UUID and max to the maximum.

Finally, a quick and dirty, but understandable approach might be to use null for none and a special value like "*" for all.